# Why Is ArrayMap Returning False when the string is in the the Array

Tags: php, arrays

I cannot figure out why the function is returning false for the input "Dash", every other value from the array will return true when tested.

```
$Valid_Links=array("Dash","Profile","Messages","Friends","Blogs","Galleries","Calendar","Settings","Logout");
//function for handling $_GET['content'] variables (uri)
    function mainHandler(){
        echo '<SECTION id="content_wrapper">';
        global $Valid_Links;
        if(isset($_GET['content'])){
            if(array_search(strtolower($_GET['content']), array_map('strtolower', $Valid_Links))){
                $doc=strtolower($_GET['content']);
                require "main/$doc.php";
            }else{echo 'false';}
        }
        else{
            if(checkLogin()){
                require 'main/dash.php';
            }
            else{
                require 'main/signup.php';
            }
        }
        echo '</SECTION>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `array_search` returns you position of the found element which is `0` in this case (first element), but `0` evaluates to FALSE when put into if statement.

**Solution:**

Add `!== FALSE` to your condition:

`if(array_search(strtolower($_GET['content']), array_map('strtolower', $Valid_Links)) !== FALSE){`

**UPDATE**

And like @VolkerK has mentioned, if you strive towards best practices you can put FALSE in front inside the IF statement. This will allow you to mitigate problems of accidentally assigning variables instead of comparing them:

`if(FALSE !== array_search(strtolower($_GET['content']), array_map('strtolower', $Valid_Links))){`

Comment: i.e. you want `if( false!==array_search(strtolower($_GET['content']), ...`

Comment: or like VolkerK mentioned - not bad practice to put boolean in front

Comment: "not bad practice to put boolean in front" - It's YodaCode. "If broken it is, fix it you must" ;-) Feels strange when you say it but putting the constant (non-lvalue) on the left side you'll get compiler/parser error if you e.g. forget the second = in `if( 0==$x )`.

Comment: The compiler/error message alone would be compelling for me. But (and that's purely an _opinion_) a comparsion often/usually has a simple and a complex side and I like the simple side to be the first one to read, so you know what the comparision is about.